# Retrieve List of resources in an active Azure subscription

Tags: php, azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to get a list of resources that belong to a give subscription. I have created an app in Azure AD, given it permissions to see subscriptions and resources.  I can get a list of subscriptions just fine.  When i attempt to get a list of resources, the list is blank, when clearly (as seen in images below) there are resources.  What am I missing?

My code:

```
  $token = getToken();
  $subId = "SomeValidSubscriptionId";
  $url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/".$subId."/resources?api-version=2019-05-10";
  $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json charset=utf-8','Authorization: Bearer '.$token));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($result);
    $res = json_decode($result,true);
    return $res;
```

The Result:

```
{"value":[]}Array
(
[value] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

Image 1: The list of resources I am trying to get:

[image]

Image 2: The permissions for 1 of the resources. proving my billingAPI app has permission to see it:

[image]

//Ignore the billingAPI123 resource, that was a failed attempt from earlier.

Answer (score 0):

the billingAPI user had a role that was not allowed to see resources.
I was using the billingReader role, when switched to owner, it works as expected.